# Ctrl+c is not working with gedit

Tags: linux, command-line, kill, gedit

When I use gedit command to try edit the a file and then pressing ctrl+c is not terminating the gedit and giving the following log

```
gedit test.sh
^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^CTraceback     most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/gedit/plugins/snippets/document.py", line 1046, in on_draw
def on_draw(self, view, ctx):
KeyboardInterrupt
```

What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> used when a  terminal window has focus sends a QUIT signal (SIGQUIT). This causes the process (in your case gedit) to terminate and dump core.

A more elegant solution is to use a terminal program such as nano  text editor instead of a GUI text editor for editing files from the terminal. The instructions for using nano editor are always found at the bottom of every page. The only two nano keyboard shortcuts that you need to know are for WriteOut and Exit. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file being edited. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano. Since nano is a terminal program, the terminal always has focus when you are using nano and the nano keyboard shortcuts always work.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl-C is normally only active if the application does not handle it itself. In any program, you can install a Ctrl-C 'handler' which will handle the keys, and do something different.

If you want a combination to save the edited contents, do Ctrl-S (for 'save') and Ctrl-Q for exiting the program.

Delicate programs, such as editors, disable Ctrl-C to abort, so you don't loose your editing by accident.